# How to pay the import fee from MyMonero.com for a paper wallet?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, cold-storage, mymonero

My current balance shows 0 XMR on MyMonero.com since my account was not yet synced with the blockchain. However, to import transactions, you must pay a fee.

I don't have the monero-wallet-cli to use with my paper wallet. Can I pay this fee by sending XMR directly from an exchange to the fee address?

Answer (score 2):

The fee must be paid to that address but the originating address does not matter. Doing this from an exchange is a valid alternative.